# Fatal error - Sanitize

Tags: php, sanitization, fatal-error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sanitize() in general.php on line 5
```

This is general.php:

```
include"connect.php"; 
function user_id_from_username($username)
{
$username   =   sanitize($username); //This is line 5/general.php
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'"),0, 'id');
}
```

connect.php contains my database connections, I have a confusion, do I need to include it in the function or functions will do it automatically connect to my database?

I am using the function in user.php As:

```
if(isset($_GET["username"])===true && empty($_GET["username"])===false)
{
$username   =   $_GET["username"];
$user_id    =   user_id_from_username($username);
echo"$user_id";
}
```

Comment: You have a backtick mismatch on line 6 at $username` - its not a protected word, so you can delete the odd `.

Comment: @Cups thanks, I got it...I did it the other way without using the function :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means exactly what it says, `sanitize` isn't defined in scope. It's not a standard function so it should be somewhere within your code. You can most likely substitute it directly with `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
$username   =  mysql_real_escape_string(username);
```

You should of course consider moving to [`PDO`](http://php.net/PDO) and parameterized queries.

Comment: Sorry, Didn't knew at that time it isn't a standad function.....